# How to change ToggleButton state programmatically?

Tags: android, togglebutton

I have a ToggleButton defined like this:

```
<ToggleButton android:text="ToggleButton" android:id="@+id/toggle"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ToggleButton>
```

And I want to change its state programmatically. I tried using the `setChecked` and `toggle` methods, but neither of those works in my situation.

I have an ongoing notification and when my activity receives the notification intent, the 
toggle button should be set to not checked, but it's not working.

I'm doing this on the activity's `onResume`. The code is being executed but the ToggleButton's state doesn't change.

Weirdly, if I call `setChecked(false)` on the activity's `onCreate` it does changes the button's state, but not on `onResume`. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Got it. Kind of.

I had this

```
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Intent intent;

        if ((intent = getIntent()) != null && MainActivity.STOP.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            disable();

            toggle.setChecked(false);

            finish();
        }
    }
```

But the call to `finish` wasn't actually doing anything. I removed it and now it works. Not a clue why this fixed it.

Someone care to explain?

Answer (score 2):

It should work.

Check that you don't have a call to `setChecked(true)` somewhere else in the code that is executed after you set it to false. Perhaps inside an `OnCheckedChangeListener`?

Comment: I know it should, but it doesn't. I don't have any other calls to `setChecked`, just searched through all the code.

Answer (score 1):

Call Finish when your activity is done and should be closed. The ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via onActivityResult().

So in your case Instead of changing the toggle Button state it goes back to its calling method which may be the onCreate() or onPause...

Details about using finish [here.....](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. I fixed it by calling ToggleButton#isChecked() method before setting the state.

```
if (mToggleSwitch.isChecked()) {
    mToggleSwitch.setChecked(false);
}
```